# I have a question about logs and limits in calculus-- it should be short

Tags: calculus

I was looking at $$\int_0^1\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{s}}\right)^2\ ds.$$

So in calculus, I would evaluate $\ln(1) - \ln(0)$ as the answer. What I don't get and I don't remember why is the answer $\infty$?

I know $\ln(1)=0$ and $\ln(0)=-\infty$

Wouldn't the answer be $-\infty$? Any explanation would be helpful. I'm forgetting some of my basic calculus.

Comment: You have to compute the *difference* of the values at each bound of the integral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer would be $0 - (- \infty) = + \infty$ (modulo technicalities, the wholesome way to write this is to say that the integral diverges to $\infty$).

Answer (score 1):

$ln(1) = 0, ln(0) \rightarrow -\infty$

$ln(1) - ln(0) \rightarrow 0 - -\infty = \infty$